# Entity Framework entity.state added versus modified at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Let's say I want to add a product then i set its state as

```
db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Added;
```

before calling the `SaveChangesAsync` but in some cases I will modify a property before which is a modification...

My question is, Do I need to call a `SaveChangesAsync` before modifying the entry and then set it as

```
db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

and call a second `SaveChangesAsync`?

thanx

Mart

Comment: If you create an entity and add it to the collection it will automatically be marked as being added. Then you save the changes. If you modify the entities properties, it will still be classed as added, because it has not been saved back to the database

Comment: if you add new product with Added state, and in the same DbContext life cycle before SaveChanges, you have some change , no need for set state to Modified.